# Efficien memory and cpu usage with progressive read and write

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose i have fetch more data rows in laravel and i have to write in csv file. And suppose my server execution time is out before all data rows are written in csv file. Then how can i proceed in order to be able to write all the data row in csv file ?

Actually i wanted to fetch data rows, clean memory and read and write data in the csv file but have no clue in laravel.

Please guys help me with any reference or ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file and having the file location stored somewhere.
Limit the records fetched once using the query.
e.g.
get the count of your required records and execute a loop according to that say 100 records at a time and write/append those records in your CSV file.

**Alternative Way (Simplest Way)**

use **Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel** library to create CSV, excel etc.

Comment: the function which generate csv file will get the datas as an array in the form of parameter. So where to save those datas and clean memory and read and write progressively? Any idead

Comment: even i do as i say what about server time out? how to solve that issues? @Anshuman Gupta

Comment: See if you are doing it manually (without any library), so just limit the records in chunks say chunks of 100 or 50.

if you are using it via library this will automatically handle server timeout issue.

Comment: I recommend using the library.
this will save your time and headache also.

The library will handle everything smoothly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959308/export-large-csv-file-using-laravel

check this out once.